# NodeJs pass parameter to callback function in 3rd party library

Tags: node.js, function, callback

There is some public library with code like this:

```
function SomeFunc(param1, param2, param3, onEnd) {
//does something
      log.ok("Finished processing: " + param1);
      onEnd();
};
```

Later, in my code, when I use this library I call a method with parameters

```
SomeFunc(value1, value2, value3, onEnd);
```

OnEnd is called when function finished tasks.

This is an implementation of OnEnd in my code that works fine

```
var onEnd = function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
};
```

As you can see, it works without parameters.
What I want to achieve, is to pass a parameter to onEnd("Something_important") but I get an error:

```
TypeError: onEnd is not a function
```

I've tried following:

```
var onEnd =function(param) { }; 
onEnd("Something_important");
```

Comment: You can return a function from the function, or .bind the function to its arguments. For more detail on Both solutions, use google / the stack overflow search engine :)

Comment: I did search for that, but still can't understand how calling function from function can help pass parameters. The parameter values are unknown from perspective of library